# jQuery Change() method not triggered in a dropdown box in Jquery DataTables

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, datatables, bootstrap-4

I have a column in a DataTable in Jquery where in each row the cell respective to the column has a dropdown box inside of it.

I am rendering this dropdown by defining it in the 'columnDefs' options as such:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').DataTable( 
"columnDefs":[
          {
              "render": function(d,t,r){
                  var $select = $("<select></select>", {
                      "id": r[1]+"start",
                        "value": d,
                        "class": r[1]
                    });
                  $.each(times, function(k,v){
                      var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                          "text": v,
                            "value": v
                        });
                        if(d === v){
                          $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                        }
                      $select.append($option);
                    });
                    return $select.prop("outerHTML");
                },
                "targets": 2
            }
        ]
)})
```

The data variable `times` in the `$.each` statement is just a variable that I am loading from `localStorage`, which consists of dates.

Since I want to wait for the data in the DataTables to be loaded before I select an item, I add an option called `initComplete` and in it I add the `change()` method as well as a method to store the change value into `localStorage`:

```
"initComplete": function(settings, json) {
$(function() {
    $('.SomeDate').change(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('storeddata', this.value);
    });
    if(localStorage.getItem('storeddata')){
        $('.SomeDate').val(localStorage.getItem('storeddata'));
    }
});
        }
```

The dropdown `<select>` tag generated in the front end looks as such:

```
<select id="SomeDatestart" value="SomeValue" class="SomeDate"></select>
```

For some reason when I select an item in the dropdown box, I don't get any results stored in the `localStorage`.

I could have made the selector select the select tag `id` instead of the select tag `class`, but even while trying that, I was not able to trigger a `change()` event.

However I tried to take the `change()` method above, and isolate it from the datatable function, and create a dummy dropdown box with the same select tag and sample `<option>` tags, and after doing that, I was able to successfully trigger the `change()` method, and similarly store the value in `localStorage`.

Am I missing something? Perhaps there is a different way of triggering the `change()` method for selections in DataTables?

Comment: Isn't there a typo (missed dot in selector) in `$('SomeDate').change(...`?

Comment: True. I updated the post accordingly.

Comment: Are you sure about having that class ('SomeDate') assigned to each cell drop-down? I can't see anything in your code doing that.

Comment: So the class `SomeDate` is being assigned for each specific dropdown in the `render` function, variable `$select.`  : `"class": r[1] `, which takes the info from the row's second cell value.  The only reason I assigned a class, was so to not have to deal with 'ids'.  The same principle in terms of the problem works if the selector was assigned to `('#SomeDatestart')`

Comment: Have you tried `$('#example').change('.SomeDate', function()...` instead of `$('.SomeDate').change(function()...`?

Comment: Oh, nice! it did trigger the change method! Thanks! However, the localStorage stored the data as 'undefined'.  I am guessing I have to do a JSON.stringify on it?

Comment: Try `localStorage.setItem('storeddata', $(this).val())`

Comment: Good suggestion! That fixed the 'undefined' part.  But it strangely returns the value as empty ("")...

Comment: You have 'storeddata' and 'storedData' within `setItem` and `getItem` isn't that another typo? Other than that I can't spot anything wrong in your code.

Comment: True, that was a typo (I updated the post)  It is strange.  I tried to look at the $(this) to see what the object gives me, and I saw this : ```"change":[{"type":"change","origType":"change","data":".SomeDate","guid":116,"selector":null,"needsContext":null,"namespace":""}]```  .  It gives the namespace as empty, and selector as null.  Maybe something to do with the way I rendered the dropdown box in columnDefs